# spring cloud data flow stream build pack

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm exploring spring cloud data flow. Part of it I deployed spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar to our private PCF. I created basic stream and tried deploying to PCF. Deployment failed because of build pack issue, stream apps by default downloading java build pack from git, our PCF is preventing it.

Is there any workaround when deploying stream from shell / data flow UI not use git build pack

Here is the error message 
Failed to clone git repository at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about the defaulting to a java-buildpack from Git (see: [CloudFoundryDeploymentProperties.java#L95](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryDeploymentProperties.java#L95)).

That's the default experience; however, it is meant to be overridden by the users to whatever the version that works best for them. That's why it is exposed a deployer property in SCDF - you can either override it as a global setting or by per-stream/per-task basis.

Example:

> cf set-env dataflow-server SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_BUILDPACK java_buildpack_offline

It is very common for PCF customers to point to an offline java-buildpack. In fact, it is even more relevant in the no-internet PCF foundation, because you'd have to default to an offline version there anyway.

You can read more about all the supported deployer properties from the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-cloudfoundry-deployer).

Comment: Thanks for quick response Sabby Anandan. I added stream deployment property (deployer.log.cloudfoundry.buildpack=java_buildpack_offline) and that solved build pack issue for me.